# Linq Except ignoring Custom comparer?

Tags: c#, linq, except

In this toy code:

```
void Main()
{
    var x = new string[] {"abc", "DEF"};
    var y = new string[] {"ABC", "def"};
    var c = new CompareCI();
    var z = x.Except(y, c);
    foreach (var s in z) Console.WriteLine(s);
}

private class CompareCI : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

It seems like the Except method is ignoring my customer comparer.  I get these results:

```
abc
DEF
```

Which looks like the case is not being ignored.  Also, when I ran it under debug and put a breakpoint at the call to string.Equals in the Customer Comparer, the breakpoint never hit, although the code ran and I got the result I posted.  i expected no results, since the sequences are equal if case is ignored.

Guess I'm doing something wrong, but I need a second pair of eyes to spot it.

Comment: No need for a custom comparer.... Try `var z = x.Except(y, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: @RuiJarimba don't know how I missed that!  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I thought it was just meant as an example. But if it's really only about an case-insensitive string comparision, then yes, use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` directly in the `Except` call, as it already is an `IEqualtiyComparer<string>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.NET Framework already provides a [StringComparer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=netframework-4.7.2), that uses specific case and culture-based or ordinal comparison rules - so in this case there is no need to create a custom comparer.

This will work:

```
var x = new string[] { "abc", "DEF" };
var y = new string[] { "ABC", "def" };
var z = x.Except(y, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: @JohnSmith so you decided to downvote an accepted answer? Yes you're right, it doesn't explain why the breakpoint wasn't hit - but it's the best solution to the OPs problem, IMO. There is no need to reivent the wheel and implement something that is already available in the .NET Framework

Answer (score 4):

Debugging your code shows that GetHashCode() is called but not Equals().

I think this is because two equal object must have equal hashcodes AND return true from Equals(). If the hashcodes are different then they cannot be equal, so there is no need to run the Equals() function.

Your code would work if the hashing function was case-insensitive, obj.ToUpper().GetHashCode().

Answer (score 1):

Modify your comparer:

```
public int GetHashCode(string obj)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Now all items will have the same hash: `0` - which means item `x` and `y` **may** be the same so calling `Equals` is required.

However, this is not recommended because returning just 0 in GetHashCode will cause performance problems.

Best option is to use built-in `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` equality comparer.

Answer (score 0):

Rui Jarimba's suggestion to use StringComparer.OriginalIgnoreCase works.

Comment: Maybe it works, but it is not an answer to your question.

Comment: Yes this should be posted as a comment, not as an answer. I'll add my answer soon